# How to get article translations in comment relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have relationship between article and translations, but how can i get that in comment?

```
$comments = ArticleComments::orderBy('created_at','desc')->with('user')->with('article')->with('translations')->paginate(10);
```

I tried this also

```
$comments = ArticleComments::orderBy('created_at','desc')->with('user')->with('article')->with('translations')->whereHas('translations',function($query) use($default_language_id){
    $query->where('language_id','=',$default_language_id);
  })->paginate(10);
```

Any suggestion? I get articles but not theirs translations...

Models:

Comment:

```
  public function article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Articles','article_id');
    }
```

Article:

```
  public function translations()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ArticleTranslations', 'article_id');
    }
```

Comment: Do you have relationship between article and comment ?

Comment: yes i have .. and i get article for that comment

Comment: please post your models code

Comment: there i posted my models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use this :

```
$comments = ArticleComments::orderBy('created_at','desc')->with('user')->with('article')->with('article.translations')->paginate(10);
```

for more information : 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships
in Nested Eager Loading section

and if you want add where to query :

```
$comments = ArticleComments::orderBy('created_at','desc')->with('user')->with('article')->with('article.translations',function($query)
    {
         $query->where('ANY CONDITION');
    })->paginate(10);
```

Comment: How can i use whereHas in article.translations ... because article.translations have field language and i want to return only where language == 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
$comments = ArticleComments::orderBy('created_at','desc')->with('user')->with('article',function ($query) {
              $query->with('translations')
              })->paginate(10);
```